# Declare 4Dimensional np.array by 2Dimensional np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I set:

```
d[i, j, i] = s[i, j] - s[i]
```

`d` is 4 dimensional `np.array`, `s` is 2 dimensional `np.array`
using NumPy and without for loop?

I've tried the follow:

```
d = np.zeros([10, 10, 10, 10])
s = np.ones([10, 10])
l1 = range(M)
l2 = range(N)
d[np.ix_(l1, l2, l1)] = s[np.ix_(l1, l2)] - s[np.ix_(l1)]
```

But it doesn't work as I want.

```
d[i, j, k] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

but I want

```
d[i, j, k] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

if i != k
```

Comment: Can you give a better example with d,s and your desired output? (not all 0s or 1s)

Comment: With that `s`, the result is all 0s.

Comment: It's not very clear..

Answer (score 0):

Giving i and j a different range to better distinguish dimensions:

The iterative solution:

```
In [271]: d = np.zeros((3,4,3,4),int)
In [272]: s = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [273]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     for j in range(4):
     ...:         d[i,j,i,:] = s[i,j]-s[i,:]
```

An array solution:

```
In [274]: d1 = np.zeros((3,4,3,4),int)
In [281]: l1=np.arange(3)
In [283]: d1[l1,:,l1,:] = (s[:,:,None]-s[:,None,:])
```

check

```
In [284]: np.allclose(d,d1)
Out[284]: True
```

and

```
In [285]: d[0,1,0,:]
Out[285]: array([ 1,  0, -1, -2])
In [286]: d[0,1,2,:]
Out[286]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
In [287]: d1[0,1,0,:]
Out[287]: array([ 1,  0, -1, -2])
In [288]: d1[0,1,1,:]
Out[288]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
In [289]: d1[1,2,2,:]
Out[289]: array([0, 0, 0, 0])
In [290]: d1[2,2,2,:]
Out[290]: array([ 2,  1,  0, -1])
```

If `s = np.ones((3,4))`, `d` is `0` for all values.

```
In [302]: d1[l1,:,l1,:].shape
Out[302]: (3, 4, 4)
In [303]: (s[:,:,None]-s[:,None,:]).shape
Out[303]: (3, 4, 4)
```

A variant on this indexing:

```
In [318]: I,J=np.ix_(l1,l2)
In [319]: I
Out[319]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
In [320]: J
Out[320]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
In [321]: d1[I,J,I,:].shape
Out[321]: (3, 4, 4)
```

a solution to your previous question was

```
In [323]: d1[I,J,I,J] = s
```